# How to investigate why the setTimeout function is not working in my code?

Tags: javascript, blockly

My code works and all values are true so that it should be running, but it does not.

I have tried localizing the variables, changing the timing, and rearranging functions and nametags.

```
auto1();  
var autocount = 0;
var autotrue = 0;

function auto1(){
    setTimeout(function() {
      while(autotrue==1){
        money = money + autocount;
        setText("money_display",money);
      }
    }, 1000);

    onEvent("auto1", "click", function(){
      if(money >= 10){autotrue = 1;
        money = money - 10;
        autocount = autocount+1;
        console.log("You now have " + autocount + " J$ per second");
      } else {
        console.log("you have insufficient J$ for this purchase");
      }
    });
}
```

I expect it to add 1 to my money variable every 1000 ms. But it does nothing to the money variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several issues with your code:

1. the `money` variable was not defined
2. The `while` loop inside the timer would make the browser freeze
3. the `timeout` should be an `interval` instead
4. `autotrue` should probably be a boolean

I faked the `setText()` function and changed `onEvent()` to `addEventListener()` for the sake of a working example:

```js
auto1();

var autocount = 0;
var autotrue = false;
var money = 10;

function auto1() {
  autoAddInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (autotrue) {
      money = money + autocount;
      setText("money_display", money);
    }
  }, 1000);
  document.getElementById('auto1').addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (money >= 10) {
      autotrue = true;
      money = money - 10;
      autocount = autocount + 1;
      console.log("You now have " + autocount + " J$ per second");
    } else {
      console.log("you have insufficient J$ for this purchase");
    }
  });
}

function setText(id, value) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerText = value + ' J$';
}

setText("money_display", money);
```

```html
balance: <span id="money_display">0 J$</span><br>
<button id="auto1">purchase +1 J$ per second</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems here:

`setTimeout` only runs once, at the end of 1000 ms. In this case, when it runs, you're going to enter an infinite loop because autotrue is never getting set true. It's still 0 and you're adding it to money and money will never get over 10 because 0+0=0.

If you wanted to repeatedly add to money every 1000 ms, you would use `setInterval`, without any loop inside. That will call your function over and over every 1000 ms.

Answer (score 0):

You call `auto1` before the variables `autocount` and `autotrue` were initialized to 0, therefore they are still `undefined` and will break your calculations. You should call that function *after* initializing all the variables.

Additionally `while(autotrue==1){` looks as if it is infinite, as there is nothing changing `autotrue`. Infinite loops are always bad.

Answer (score 0):

Take this out and you will see that the timer works.

```
  while(autotrue==1){
    money = money + autocount;
    setText("money_display",money);
```

Your problem is that you are not setting the autotrue var to 1 anywhere.